# Seeing "Page Not Found" on Activity, Members, Groups & Blogs tabs

Tags: plugins, wordpress, buddypress

I have installed the latest version of BuddyPress on a WP.

However, the Activity, Members, Groups, and Blogs tabs all show "Page not found" errors. or show me just a title.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

screenshot: http://oi43.tinypic.com/14cw45v.jpg

[link here](http://oi43.tinypic.com/14cw45v.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue just now. All of my buddypress pages (register, activate, members, etc.) were giving me a 404 error. I now have all the pages displaying correctly.

### EXPERIENCE

I'm using an amazon EC2 instance, with apache2. My buddypress was version 2.2.1 on wordpress 4.1.1.

My first guess was that the URL wasn't rewriting correctly, so I tried all of the options in settings > permalinks.

Each time I reloaded the page I was trying to access and confirmed that my .htaccess file was being rewritten accordingly.

(.htaccess is in the base directory of your wordpress installation. If it isn't being rewritten by saving wordpress' permalinks options, try chmod-ing the permissions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).

### SOLUTION

I found a solution through the permalinks page of the wordpress codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

There is an option is a file called httpd.conf on my system that disabled the rewrite module in my .htaccess file. (On a linux system this should be in /etc/httpd/conf. On OSX it should be in /etc/apache2.)

By changing my webserver directory AllowOverride option from None to All, the .htaccess file was able to function properly. Again, I found a line in the  section of my httpd.conf file that read:

`AllowOverride None`

and changed it to:

`AllowOverride All`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to settings/permalinks, and just save them again. Often this resolved 'page not found' errors.

Comment: What should I do in permalinks, 
Would I change anything? or what's

Comment: Nope, just save, then refresh your pages. If that does not work then it's something else.